# Sharing data using HttpContext.Cache within a ASP.NET application between multiple worker processes?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, memcached

Is it possible to share an object between worker processes using the [HttpContext.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.cache.aspx)?  If not is there an alternative method to sharing data between processes?

Comment: What kind of data do you want to share?

Comment: @John - I'm trying to store a log of sql queries, execution times, and exception messages.  I built a sql wrapper class which holds this information.  I serialize the log into an xml file on session or application end events.  I do not want to store this data to disk per request.

Comment: I'm looking for some kind of distributed memcache object sharing feature built into .NET

Comment: Why not use a logging framework? Maybe even just Trace.WriteLine?

Comment: I'm also using singleton objects to cache my site configuration.  I've got db connection strings, custom membership and roles providers, and a plugin framework which loads MVC objects from dll assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. One way of sharing objects would be using session in database strategy.
[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx) you have a link with some info about storing the session in the database

Another option would be using a distributed cache like memcached or AppFabric.